# Python: how to generate a unique identifier for an XML document?

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, xslt-1.0, uuid

XSLT has a generate-id(*xml-document*) function. With it I can create a unique identifier for an XML document.

In Python how would I generate a unique identifier for an XML document?

Note: the unique identifier should be based on the content of the XML document, not the file name of the XML document. For example, this XML document

```
<root>
   <comment>Hello, World</comment>
</root>
```

and this XML document

```
<document>
   <test>Blah, Blah</test>
</document>
```

must generate different identifiers, even if their file names are identical.

I have a graph of XML documents. So I need some way to recognize, "Hey, I've already seen this XML document." I don't want to compare entire XML documents. Instead, I want to compare UUIDs that correspond to the XML.

Comment: The UUID module could be used to do this.  Its available in python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A colleague just sent me the answer:

> For mapping text to an ID, we’ve used MD5 as one hash digest. Give the
>   md5() function an XML document (string) and it will return a
>   32-character identifier.

More details:

---

### genid.py

```
import sys
import stdio
from hashlib import md5

def digest_md5(obj):
    if type(obj) is unicode:
        obj = obj.encode('utf8')
    return md5(obj).hexdigest()

s = sys.stdin.readline()
stdio.writeln(digest_md5(s))
```

Then I turned it into an exe file.

Then from a DOS command prompt I typed this command:

```
type input.txt | genid
```

where input.txt is:

```
<Document>Hello, World</Document>
```

And I got this output:

```
df6f8283335bf3f657a89733e3d36b84
```

Beautiful!

Answer (score 0):

```
import uuid
unique_id = uuid.uuid1()
```

You can also generate hexadecimal id or integer id by

```
uuid.uuid1().hex    # For hexadecimal id
uuid.uuid1().int    # For integer id
```

Comment: Does the uuid1() function take an argument? Specifically, can I give it an XML document as an argument: "Hey, please generate a UUID to represent this XML document"?

Comment: No it does not take any argument. What you can do is associate your document with this id in some or other way(like saving in a file named by this id or appending id as a tag in your xml file)

Comment: Thanks Naman. What you suggest won't work for me. What I am seeking is a way to generate an identifier based on the content of the XML document. That way, if I encounter an XML document that is the same one that I saw earlier, I can tell that it's the same by generating its identifier and comparing the identifier against other identifiers seen earlier. (Think of a graph of XML documents. I need to recognize "Hey, I've already seen this XML document")

Answer (score 0):

```
import uuid

#Create unique filename
uid = uuid.uuid1() # Generate UUID
uidstr = str(uid.int)[:21]
clientoneID = "8888"
OrderID = (clientoneID + uidstr)

#Save unique xmlfile
xmlf = open(OrderID, 'w')
xmlf.write(xmlfile)#Content of your XML file
xmlf.close
```